# How to call a macro variable based on a condition

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset in SAS with

- a variable *condition*, that can take values in *"01",...,"20"*
- several variables indexed by *i*, for instance *var01*, ..., *var20*

What i want to do is to create a new variable *total* which is equal to *vark* if *condition=k*. I can do it by several if... else statement (it is what I do for now), but I did not manage to do it in a more compact and elegant way.

I tried

```
data want;
set have;
    call symput(condition, temp);
    total=var&temp;
run;
```

But it does not work... At best with some tries with resolve instructions I wan get a *total* value that equals 'var01' and so on, but just the characters, not the values associated to the variable *var01*

My goal is to do better than

```
data want  ;
set have (keep=noi nomen var01-var20 lprm condition ag);
if condition="01" then varpr=var01;
else if condition="02" then varpr=var02;
else if condition="03" then varpr=var03;
else if condition="04" then varpr=var04;
else if condition="05" then varpr=var05;
else if condition="06" then varpr=var06;
else if condition="07" then varpr=var07;
else if condition="08" then varpr=var08;
else if condition="09" then varpr=var09;
else if condition="10" then varpr=var10;
else if condition="11" then varpr=var11;
else if condition="12" then varpr=var12;
else if condition="13" then varpr=var13;
else if condition="14" then varpr=var14;
else if condition="15" then varpr=var15;
else if condition="16" then varpr=var16;
else if condition="17" then varpr=var17;
else if condition="18" then varpr=var18;
else if condition="19" then varpr=var19;
else if condition="20" then varpr=var20;
run;
```

Thanks

Comment: The key thing to understand here is that SAS resolves `&temp` before the data step is even run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different solution, not using arrays, using the vvaluex function:

```
varpr = vvaluex(catt('var', condition));
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002233818.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a macro variable that way - it has to be defined outside of the data step.

However, you can use arrays for this, if I understand your purpose.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array var[20] var01-var20;
  total=var[condition];
run;
```

Comment: My purpose is to select the value of the correct var_i variable in a new variable, the correct var_i being the one with the i which is in 'condition'. For instance, for one observation for which condition="02", i want to have total=var02 (the value of it, var02 is a variable I have along with var01... and so on).

Comment: Right.  That's what this does.  (You would need to make sure condition was a numeric, if it's character then `input` it.)

Comment: I have tried `condition_2=input(condition,2.)` (which is indeed a character), but it does not work

Comment: "It does not work" isn't specific enough to help. Your variables have leading zeros in front of them, so to put them in an array, you'd add `var01-var20` to the end of the `array` statement. You could also just put the `input` function right in the array subscript like this: `total=var[input(condition,2.)];`.

Comment: Edited to reflect the variable names being 0 padded.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create a small macro with loop.

Idea is

%Macro cond;

%do i=1 %to 20;

If condition="&i" then out_var=in_&var;

%end;

%mend;

Use this macro in data step.

I hope this can solve your purpose.